# Remove UTF-8 hex formated text from filename on bash

Tags: bash

I am working on API which will fetch data from a website and make it easier to use for broadcasting. Now, I noticed that someone decided to use emoji on one of their URLs and now I am having hard time to get it out so I can use that URL as well on my API.

When I request the URL, it will add the emoji in UTF-8 hex format after the URL.

For example,  in the URL turns to %f0%9f%98%8d when downloading the page. Now, I want to get that hex format gone and I have already spent hours on trying different regex/sed/awk/perl commands and nothing seems to get to what I want.

Basically, just remove the trailing emoji code from the filename, that would be golden.

Comment: it's not "utf-8 hex formatted", it's [URL Encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Why exactly does the percent-encoded URL not work for you? In other words, in what context are you trying to use the URL (or URL component)?

Comment: @rici Since API will only listen for proper URLs. I am trying to make it user friendly, so they can easily use the API and not jump over hoops getting it correctly working. Also, it looks nicer when it has no emojis since its NodeJS based API

Comment: It certainly looks nicer with the emojis included, but you can use the percent-encoded string as a URL (as long as you don't percent-encode it again). Anyway, in javascript, you can use [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) or [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). Make sure you understand the difference between the two so as to decide which one you need. Doing it in bash will be a lot trickier.

Comment: Can you give the full URL of a problematic link?  The only links I have saved have emojis in the description (taken from page title) but those are not embedded in the actual URL itself.  Just wondering if that is the same for you or something different?

Comment: `filename='a%f0%9f%98%8db'; echo "${filename//%??}";` prints `ab`.